# When i run a test in protractor instead of opening the given link in browser it gives error(please check image)

Tags: automation, jasmine, protractor

So when i execute a simple calculator program from VS- Studio and when the browser opens ...everytime it is same(plz refer image) tried lot but everytime same error. I followed  lot of tutorial for protractor automation tool..no progress

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are running integration tests using karma

I am sure you are using `ng test`

Which will run integration test. I mean the spec file inside your component will be run using karma

Use `ng e2e` to run protractor tests.